# What does an EXEC command do in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am presently updating a procedure with multiple EXEC lines such as:

```
EXEC    databasename.tablename.pr_sys_drop_Object 'zt_Staging_of_class'
```

yet nowhere have I found the definition of EXEC in this context.

Comment: What do you mean by "in this context"?

Comment: "in this context" is executing the `databasename.tablename.pr_sys_drop_Object` stored procedure

Comment: @Lamak No offence, but I am trying to give the OP a chance to avoid a -1 by explaining why a Google search of "sql exec" wasn't sufficient.

Comment: @DeanOC Sorry, my comment wasn't directed to you (hadn't even read your previous comment), was just answering op's question

Comment: Why was this just down voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a full three part name where the middle part is not the name of a table but of a *schema* a kind of SQL namespace. So in that context `pr_sys_drop_Object` is a stored procedure in a separate schema.

If you look in the named database, in the named schema you'll probably find a stored procedure called `pr_sys_drop_Object`.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly wht I was trying to discern

Answer (score 2):

Execute is a sql server keyword see the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) for more details.  It is used to execute stored procedures or raw sql.

In your case it seems to be executing the procedure databasename.tablename.pr_sys_drop_Object and passing in 'zt_Staging_of_class' as a parameter to that procedure.